# JAX-RS annotations

Tags: jersey, cxf, jax-rs

I want to learn Restful web service using Apache CXF. Could you please suggest any resource to refer to except for the official CXF site? Where can I learn all those annotations with example uses?

One more question is “Are those annotations going to be different depending on the implementations framework like apache CXF or Jersey or any other framework?”

Answer (score 4):

> Are those annotations going to be different depending on the implementations framework like apache cxf or jersey or any other framework?

No. The point of the JAX-RS standard (and the rest of Java EE) is exactly to ensure the annotations work the same across implementations. Of course, there will always be bugs and differences in interpretation that result in different behavior, but in general it tends to work pretty well.

However, there may be *additional*, implementation-specific annotations that provide desirable functionality that is not covered by the standard (there's quite a lot of these for EJB and JPA implementations, not sure about JAX-RS). Using those would make your app depend on that particular implementation.

Comment: As long as you're not attaching documentation to the generated WADL, you can use CXF with just standard annotations. OTOH, the way you assemble the components into an application is different in CXF and Jersey (they make a number of different assumptions) so your code is unlikely to be directly portable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jersey user guide - it has a section on JAX-RS, which explains these annotations and should work with any other JAX-RS implementation: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF documentation is very useful and it provides lots of additional resources. Consider going through it and checking the examples.

Additionally it might be useful for you to go through some JAXB tutorials and resources.